# Access prototype function within a prototype function

Tags: javascript, function, prototype, prototype-programming

I'm trying to call **login** function defined in prototype but the function make the call (**refresh**) is also in the prototype.

```
function Checker() {
        var self = this;
        self.refresh();
        window.setInterval(function(){self.refresh()}, 1000);

}
Checker.prototype = {

        refresh: function() {
             if(some condition){
                 login(); // this won't work, neither self.login();
             }
        },
        login: function() {

        }
};
```

How do I call login function within refresh function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a prototype method, the instance is set to `this`.  So `this.login()` is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

That's simple: Use `this.login()`